# "That's got carpet tile written all over it. "?

Tags: meaning, context

I'm watching a british TV show "The Great British Bake Off" and stumbled upon this conversation.

(One contestant(B) trying to pull out a cake lifter after placing a cake on a stand. Another person(A) overlooking that and says,)

> A: "That's got carpet tile written all over it."
>   B: "Asking for disaster."

Could someone tell me what is this means please?

Comment: There are exceptions, of course, but since carpet tile is _usually_ at the lower end of the spectrum as far as cost and quality goes, my immediate interpretation of this was "looks good, but is of poor quality"

Answer (score 4):

Since it's being said while someone is doing something that risks the cake's balance, the most likely explanation is that it means the cake is likely to fall (onto the carpet tile). One of the meanings of "written all over it" is to be a [perfect match for something](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+name+written+all+over+it); also consider the idiom of "a bullet with his name on it", meaning a bullet destined to be used on a specific person. The person is essentially saying that the cake is destined to hit the carpet tile. The comment "asking for disaster" reinforces this interpretation.

Answer (score 0):

A carpet tile is thin. Presumably, the cake had not risen as intended and was as thin as a carpet tile.

The idiom "*has x written all over it*" can be used in different contexts, but here it means *to show a certain characteristic very clearly*. Source: [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20(something)%20written%20all%20over%20it).

Comment: I think the intended meaning could have been a number of things - eg that it was destined to be dropped and splattered all over the floor, thus ending up like a carpet tile. Regardless, the main point about the meaning of "written all over it" is correct.

Comment: It's worth pointing out as well that "written all over it" is often (perhaps *most* often) used within a prediction of the future, rather than describing the object's current state: so in this case it's like saying *"I think that this might end up resembling a carpet tile"*

Comment: @Max Williams. Agreed. Maybe Person A was implying that the cake was only fit to be dropped on the floor and stamped on!

Comment: I think that would be way too cruel/discouraging for the show in question - nobody would make that sort of comment, not even the "bad cop" judge Paul Hollywood (unless it was about their own cake, isn't the case here I think).

Comment: @MaxWilliams I think you are right about the splat, but I'd say its because it ends up *on* the carpet tiles, rather than resembling them. The next words spoken are 'Oh, nicely done' suggesting that the cake lifter was indeed removed without the cake falling. https://subsaga.com/bbc/entertainment/the-great-british-bake-off/series-4/8-quarter-final.html

Comment: @Spagirl FWIW, there's no carpet at all in the GBBO kitchen - carpets and frenzied cake baking do not mix well.

Comment: @MaxWilliams Isn't there? Looks like it to me. (I did check before I commented) http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-3767770/That-s-way-cookies-tumble-Bake-fans-left-edge-seats-Val-drops-biscuits-picks-offers-judges.html

Comment: @Spagirl whoops, yes, you're totally right, it is not just carpet but carpet tiles.  Even in the wide shots, it's clearly carpeted, eg https://www.thehomewarescompany.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/paul-hollywood.jpg  Which actually just makes the comment simpler to understand, they probably just meant "There's a good chance you might drop it.".  Who puts carpet in a kitchen?  That's just crazy....

Comment: @MaxWilliams I knew I could persuade you to my way of thinking. FWIW I have carpet tiles in my kitchen, they help it be warmer and if something wet gets spilled I can lift the tile to the sink to clean, or at a push replace the single tile from my stock of spares. V practical.

Comment: Not as practical as regular tiles, IMO, although warmness and less worry about my children smashing their heads open does sway me.  But I think we're getting off topic here...